# Could not find multi_json-1.10.1 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

Tags: ruby, bundler

I did a `bundle install` but am getting this error message (again):

```
/Users/snowcrash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/bundler-1.7.11/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize': Could not find multi_json-1.10.1 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

I've tried `bundle install` but no good.

Suggestions?

==== UPDATE

```
$ bundle list | grep json
  * json (1.8.2)
  * multi_json (1.10.1)
```

Looking through my Gemfile it seems I didn't have `multi_json` specified in the Gemfile. I added it:

```
gem 'multi_json', '>=1.10.1'
```

re-ran `bundle install` and then got:

```
Could not find sprockets-2.2.3 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

So, I added this to the Gemfile:

```
gem 'sprockets', '>=2.2.3'
```

and `bundle list` gives:

```
* sprockets (2.2.3)
```

Then, re-ran `bundle install` but still get:

```
Could not find sprockets-2.2.3 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

If it helps I have the following gems installed:

```
$ gem list | grep sprockets
middleman-sprockets (3.3.1)
sprockets (2.11.0, 2.10.0)
```

Comment: Show your Gemfile. Also, what does `bundle list` get you?

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

```
gem uninstall bundler
```

At least, compass and other stuff started working after removing bundler.